# How to draw a shape with transform matrix with konva?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I want to draw a rect or ellipse with a transform matrix with konva.but i cannot find the function like "setTransform"

In my xml,I have to draw a rect with some information like :

The position is the center point, the (10,10) is the left-top of the rect, the (50,80) is the width and height of the rect.how could i use the transform matrix to draw the rect?

```
var rectObj = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 50,
  height: 80,
  fill: "ffff0000",
  stroke: "ffff0000"
});
//how to use the transform matrix???
return rectObj;
```

I want to draw a rect with transform matrix

Comment: my transform matrix is transform="0.965926,-0.258819,0.258819,0.965926,0,0"

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to "decompose" transformation matrix into properties of the shapes:

```
// from https://github.com/Fionoble/transformation-matrix-js/blob/fc38603c6ae43e1fde72e14bb8e22420c574eea3/src/matrix.js#L438
function decompose(me) {
  var a = me.a,
      b = me.b,
      c = me.c,
      d = me.d,
      acos = Math.acos,
      atan = Math.atan,
      sqrt = Math.sqrt,
      pi = Math.PI,

      translate = {x: me.e, y: me.f},
      rotation  = 0,
      scale     = {x: 1, y: 1},
      skew      = {x: 0, y: 0},

      determ = a * d - b * c;   // determinant(), skip DRY here...


  if (a || b) {
    var r = sqrt(a*a + b*b);
    rotation = b > 0 ? acos(a/r) : -acos(a/r);
    scale = {x:r, y:determ/r};
    skew.x = atan((a*c + b*d) / (r*r));
  }
  else if (c || d) {
    var s = sqrt(c*c + d*d);
    rotation = pi * 0.5 - (d > 0 ? acos(-c/s) : -acos(c/s));
    scale = {x:determ/s, y:s};
    skew.y = atan((a*c + b*d) / (s*s));
  }
  else { // a = b = c = d = 0
    scale = {x:0, y:0};     // = invalid matrix
  }

  return {
    scale    : scale,
    position: translate,
    rotation : rotation,
    skew     : skew
  };
}

// parse transformation string into matrix object
function parseTransform(string) {
  var parts = string.split(',');
  return {
    a: parseFloat(parts[0]),
    b: parseFloat(parts[1]),
    c: parseFloat(parts[2]),
    d: parseFloat(parts[3]),
    e: parseFloat(parts[4]),
    f: parseFloat(parts[5]), 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it to apply attrs:

```
var transform="0.965926,-0.258819,0.258819,0.965926,0,0";
var matrix = parseTransform(transform);
var attrs = decompose(matrix);

shape.setAttrs({
  x: attrs.position.x,
  y: attrs.position.y,
  scaleX: attrs.scale.x,
  scaleY: attrs.scale.y,
  skewX: attrs.skew.x,
  skewY: attrs.skew.y,
  rotation: attrs.rotation /  Math.PI * 180
})
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/bezatihoye/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: shape.setAttrs({
  x: attrs.position.x,
  y: attrs.position.y,
  scaleX: attrs.scale.x,
  scaleY: attrs.scale.y,
  skewX: attrs.skew.x,
  skewY: attrs.skew.y,
  rotation: attrs.rotation /  Math.PI * 180
}) I think the x and y should be the offset of the origin x and y，but when i have a rotation before transform，how should i change the rotation？

Comment: you can use the `position` above to apply to the offset. It depends on your use case.

Comment: i have a rotation before transform，how should i change the rotation？plus them together?

Comment: Yes, try to do that